# How i can say browser to stop caching the mine page in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox

I have a web-page where i load second page using jQuery ajax and page also load the css who i load from jQuery code instead of embeded html code [in head tag].

the problem is that both Chrome and firefox does not refresh the partial page if i make something change.

in the partial page partial.html if i change something and make refresh none of them change them in chrome it's work using CTRL +R  but Firefox does not know that page goes changed they still produce the old things.

that's the problem i have. how i can told browser firefox to stop caching my page.

Comment: Are you the REAL Steven Spielberg?

Comment: in firefox CTRL+F5 is for hard refresh and chrome SHIFT+F5

Comment: i am steven and i am from india. off-couse second person  have same name and popularity. no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is classically solved by changing the URL of the loaded data every time you use it. For instance, you could add a parameter of random data to the URL like this:

```
var url = "http://example.com/page.php?foo=bar&random=" + Math.random();
```

To create an URL that is different every time, but leads to the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a URL variable to fix caching issues e.g. :

```
var u = "http://www.nocacheplease.com/test.aspx?v=" + new Date().getTime();
```